# Redraw MKAnnotationView

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkannotationview

Depends of zoom level of MKMapView I need to redraw my custom MKAnnotationView. As far, as I understood I must to do it in next method of map controller

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

Removing and then adding annotation to MKMapView here force blinking of AnnotationView.
How can I do this in a right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to remove it and add it back. Just make a change on the custom annotation view and call `setNeedsDisplay`. Example:

```
@interface AnnotationClusterView : MKAnnotationView {
@property (nonatomic, assign) int badgeNumber;
}
@implementation AnnotationClusterView
@synthesize badgeNumber;
// ...
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.badgeNumber];
    [string drawInRect:stringRect withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13.0]];
}
@end
```

When zoom changes, get a reference to the MKAnnotationView, set a different badgeNumber, and ask for a redraw calling `[myView setNeedsDisplay];`. You can do the same for images.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was going crazy trying to find a problem with my custom Annotation views. It turned out that after I assigned a new annotation to an existing view - it was not redrawing the view. Using SetNeededDisplay fixed the problem.

Comment: Make sure you call setNeedsDisplay from the mapView and not from itself, I spent one whole day to find out that calling `[self setNeedsDisplay];` doesn't make `drawRect:` to be executed.